# Login User using NodeJs from MySQL after password has been hashed using dcrypt

Tags: mysql, node.js, bcrypt

I'm creating a login and registration app using NodeJs and MySQL. I hashed the passwords using bcrypt however i'm unable to log in using email and password after user has registered. Kindly assist

Below is the registration code snippet

```
// registration
router.post('/register', (req,res)=>{
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email= req.body.email;
    var password= req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;
    let errors = [];

    //Check required fields
    if(!name || !email || !password || !password2){
        errors.push({msg: 'Please fill in all the fields'});
        res.send({message:'Please fill in all the fields'});
    }

    //Check passwords match
    if(password != password2){
        console.log('Passwords dont match');
        errors.push({msg: 'Passwords dont match'});
        res.send({message:'Passwords dont match'});
    }

    if(errors.length>0){

    }else{
        if(email){
            db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], 
            (error, results, fields)=>{
                if (results.length>0){
                    res.send('Email exists');
                }else{
                    res.send('Reg success')
                    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
                        if(err)throw err;
                        password = hash;
                        db.query('INSERT INTO users(name, email, password) VALUES("'+name+'", "'+email+'", "'+password+'")',
                       [name, email, password]);
                      });
                }
            });
            }else{
                res.send('Enter Email');
            };
    }
    });
```

And Here is the login code snippet

```
// login
router.post('/login', (req, res)=> {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    const bcryptPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, hash);

    if (email && bcryptPassword) {
        db.query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [email,bcryptPassword], 
        (error, results, fields)=> {
            if (results.length > 0 ) {
                res.send("Successful");
            } else {
                res.send('Incorrect Email and/or Password!');
            }           
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        res.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Be sure to use *prepared statements with placeholder values* to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This is necessary to ensure any values are properly escaped and won't cause problems. Most drivers have this capability, and those like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) make it easy so there's really no excuse to not do it.

Comment: You're hashing the password, and then bizarrely *inserting the plain-text password instead*. You're using placeholders in the login part, but not in the first, which is a huge problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashing the same plaintext twice, even with the same salt will not give the same hash.

You should select the hash from the user table for the email and then run:

```
bcrypt.compareSync(myPlaintextPassword, hash); // true
```

This should tell you true or false whether the password from the input and the hash in db are a match.

[bcrypt: To check a password - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-check-a-password-1)

Something like this:

```
// login
router.post('/login', (req, res)=> {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  if (email && password) {
    db.query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], 
      (error, results, fields)=> {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, {hash from db})) {
            res.send("Successful");
        } else {
            res.send('Incorrect Email and/or Password!');
        }           
        res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
    res.end();
  }
});
```

also: [bcrypt: Why is async mode recommended over sync mode?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#why-is-async-mode-recommended-over-sync-mode)

> If you are using bcrypt on a simple script, using the sync mode is perfectly fine. However, if you are using bcrypt on a server, the async mode is recommended. This is because the hashing done by bcrypt is CPU intensive, so the sync version will block the event loop and prevent your application from servicing any other inbound requests or events. The async version uses a thread pool which does not block the main event loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It's not `dcrypt`, just `bcrypt`. This should works:

```
// login
router.post('/login', (req, res)=> {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    const dcryptPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, hash); // this one was incorrect

    if (email && dcryptPassword) {
        db.query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [email,dcryptPassword], 
        (error, results, fields)=> {
            if (results.length > 0 ) {
                res.send("Successful");
            } else {
                res.send('Incorrect Email and/or Password!');
            }           
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        res.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: This can't work. Bcrypt produces different hashes each time by design. The solution is to pull the hash from the database and compare it then.